# Run R script from terminal with a ggplot2 object and custom font (invalid font type)

Tags: r, macos, terminal, command

I have a script that works just fine in R and RStudio, but when I run `Rscript mycode.R` in Terminal (macOS) it returns the following error:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  invalid font type
Calls: stocks_report ... drawDetails -> drawDetails.text -> grid.Call.graphics
Execution halted
```

I know that it is happening because I use the `lares::theme_lares2()` function which sets the plot's font to 'Arial Narrow'. But, why is it having problems to run through terminal?

Little reproducible example. This code runs just fine. You can save it into `mycode.R` file.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lares) # devtools::install_github("laresbernardo/lares")
data(diamonds)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price)) + geom_boxplot() + theme_lares2()
```

Try running `Rscript mycode.R` and will return the same error.

PS: Please, patience installing the `lares` library... it has lots of dependencies. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

if this is your code, then It probably is because you aren't telling R to output your plot to a file. This is fine as it will auto plot it in Rstudio, but in command line there are no graphics. I would try to add something of the manner from [saving graphics](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html) here

```
pdf("where_file.pdf")
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price)) + geom_boxplot() + theme_lares2()
dev.off()
```

Comment: Ok I get what you are saying. Actually what I think I should do is like an invisible() creation of plots that are later added to a Rmd report. Let me try that and see if the font issue persists